# HTML5: drag out a JS generated file

Tags: javascript, file, html, drag-and-drop

I have a feeling security concerns may not allow this but is it possible to generate a file with JavaScript and allow the user to drag it to the desktop (or file system)?

The following code drags out a file from a server

```
files[0].addEventListener("dragstart",function(evt){
    evt.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", "application/octet-stream:Eadui2.ttf:http://thecssninja.come/demo/gmail_dragout/Eadui.ttf");
},false);
```

And with the below code I can generate a file and have it download but I can't set the file name or let the user select the location.

```
var uriContent = "data:application/octet-stream," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(map));
location.href = uriContent;
```

Ideally I'd like a magical combination of both.

Comment: Why don't you try saving it to the server first, then downloading it, then deleting it from the server?

Comment: Have you tried `files[0].addEventListener("dragstart",function(evt){ 
    evt.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", "application/octet-stream:Eadui2.ttf:data:application/octet-stream," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(map)); 
); 
},false); `  ???

Comment: @Andrew Yes that's an option, my client wanted the app to have no server interaction but that might be the only way to do it.

Comment: See my answer, it should work. I'm sure there's a security issue with JavaScript generating then downloading content but it could be a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible for Chrome, and even in Chrome you can't set the location. If using only Chrome is okay then you will have the following options:

1. Stick with Drag n' Drop like from the CSS Ninja's tutorial, then you should try Ben's answer. `encodeURIComponent` is one way, but if you have the file generated using `BlobBuilder` then you can use `window.webkitURL.createObjectURL()` to get the file's URL. You can also try using `FileWriter()` with `requestFileSystem(TEMPORARY, ...)`.
2. Chrome supports `download` attribute for anchor tags so you can have regular link for the user to click (dragging also works):

   `<a href="#your_url" download="filename.ext">Download</a>`
3. For cross browser support I suggest [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify).

Answer (score 3):

following code is currently working in Chrome only:

```
// generate downloadable URL, file name here will not affect stored file
var url = URL.createObjectURL(new File([JSON.stringify(map)], 'file_name.txt'));
// note that any draggable element may be used instead of files[0]
// since JSON.stringify returns a string, we use 'text' type in setData
files[0].addEventListener("dragstart", function(evt) {
  evt.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", "text:file_name.txt:" + url);
}, false);
```

now, dragging our files[0] element from the browser to desktop or file system, will store there a text file called, file_name.txt.

Feel free to choose another file name :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try sending it to the server, saving the file, checking the return value and firing the download file function, followed by a server file that deletes the file from the server.

Something like this (with jQuery)

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'saveFile.php',
  method: 'post',
  data: {
     Filedata: data// file data variable
  },
  success: function(d) {
    // save file function, where d is the filename
  }
})
```

PHP:
    $filename = ;//generate filename
    file_put_contents($filename, $_POST['Filedata']);
    echo $filename;

Obviously there is more to it but that should be the basics